# How do I extract the last two values from while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, extract

I have a while loop, which I use to determine the thickness of a layer to reduce intensity of radiation to half. But because I want more precise result I want to extract last two values so that I can then use them for linear interpolation.

Here is the code:

```
t = 0
while sum_2 > sum_ker / 2:    # sum_ker is the radiation before attenuation 
    sum_2 = 0
    for i in range(len(mu_Cu):
        c = ker[i] * np.exp(- mu_Cu[i] * t)
        sum_2 = sum_2 + c
    t = t + 0.001
```

where 't' is the values I need, except not only the one once while ends. I need the one before that too.

Thanks

Edit:
When I asked about 't' I actually meant the values of sum_2. 't' is kind of easy to get. I'm sorry, if I don't see something obvious again.

Comment: If you need the values of `t` you should show where `t` is defined. Also, this loop is irrelevant to the value of `t`.

Comment: could you please show an example of mu_Cu and ker imputs and desired output? also, you must try to avoid `range(len(var)) : ` you could get the same result with:

for thisMu,thisKer in zip(mu_Cu,ker): 
 C = thisKet * np.exp(- thisMu *t)

...

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim yeah, sorry, forgot to include the main loop there

Comment: @UlisesBussi Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but `t` appears to only add .001 to the value each iteration, so couldn't you just subtract `.001` and `.002` to get the last two values?

Comment: @JNevill Yeah, you are right. I spent so much on time that totally missed that...Thanks
I will have to edit the question tho, because I need the respective values of sum_2 aswell...yeah I messed it up...well